# How to get rid of Adobe Update notifier

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I am working on Windows XP. Every day at 2 AM I have Adobe update notifier icon in the system tray. I don't want anything to be loaded without my permission. I disabled it in msconfig startup. But it still starts.

The name of the process is:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\UWA\AAM Updates Notifier.exe

[image]

How to stop this stuff?

Comment: What about in your services list, is it in there and being started automatically?

Comment: > "is it in there and being started automatically?" Maybe, it's Adobe LM service?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what it will be called. It's just another place that automatically started processes can live.

Comment: Quick search on "LM Service" reveals that it is DRM/spyware that installs with CS5 (see http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/321444.html). If you disable it, CS5 may not work anymore. So I don't think that's it.

Comment: This thread is talking about the AAM process and has some suggestions for removing: http://www.thaivisa.com/forum/topic/546174-adobe-flash-player-update/. Might be useful, but it just came up in search results, I can't vouch for any of the options they give.

Comment: Also, the Sysinternals utilities that @root suggests are very good. It is worth trying them out.

Comment: I disabled this service and it's not running. But CS5 works fine.

Comment: > "Also, the Sysinternals utilities that @root suggests are very good. It is worth trying them out." I downloaded and tried it already.

Answer (score 6):

`msconfig` only shows a small subset of the startup applications.

Instead, you should consider using [Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). This is a free utility from Microsoft, and it gives a more comprehensive list of what is set to start up automatically.

Also, you might want to check the preferences of the Adobe applications that you have installed. Running one of those applications might start the updater service even if it was disabled from Autoruns.

Answer (score 3):

Updater was located in the scheduled tasks. I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

I hate programs that start at computer start up without asking my permision and stay in memory all day long doing god knows what with MY computer.

So, as an EXTREME measure, go to the c:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\UWA\ folder and simply delete that little piece of garbage. That's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Reader/Acrobat, Edit > Preferences > Updater, turn off updates.

Comment: I don't have acrobat reader.I have Adobe fireworks CS5. Probably, it has added it. But there is no option to disable the updater.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried disabling it in Task Manager, but we'll see...

There is a thread about this on the Adobe forums, and according to Adobe, "it's necessary" for it to run all the time, which as a user on their forums points out, is absurd.  Apparently this is done intentionally, and as Adobe has claimed it does more than just look for updates, in writing, there is a theory it is collecting user data (effectively Adobe's own spyware it won't let you get rid of).

https://community.adobe.com/t5/download-install-discussions/how-to-kill-aam-adobe-updater-completely/td-p/4563952